# swapping values in c to reverse array but the array/memory blocks remain unchanged

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, reverse, swap

I just wanted to reverse the array. it seems the below snippet of code has some problem.
(first question here and not well-versed with c yet.)
PROBLEM:
Even after this block of code executed the values in array remain same.

At first, I used malloc() to allocate memory for elements of an array,
and later used static array.
Also changed temp to pointer type,
prevented direct assignment by creating another temp(eg. lamp), initialized them with dynamic memory.
Also, I did it without using dereference operator.
But nothing was solved.
The problem seems to lie in this code. But I haven't come to recognize it.

I found appropriate code instructing to *create new array/memory blocks* to collect values and assign them and print but it is not the method I would normally think to do.

Welcome to all answers. thanks for the help!

```
     for(i=0;i<num;i++)
   
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[num-(i+1)];
       arr[num-(i+1)] =temp;
    }
```

Comment: You need to iterate only over *half* of the array. Otherwise you will swap each pair  twice. Aside: The array indexing notation (that is `arr[i]`) is much more clean and readable

Comment: or you can also use two index variables, like `for(i=0,j=num-1;i<j;++i,--j)`

Comment: @tevemadar ... or `for(i=0,j=num;i < j--;++i)` or the like to allow `num == 0` with  `size_t` for `i, j`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your response, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a wrong condition in the for loop

```
 for(i=0;i<num;i++)
         ^^^^^
```

For example if you have an array of two elements

```
int arr[2] = { 1, 2 };
```

then after the first iteration of the loop when `i` is equal to `0` the array will be

```
{ 2, 1 }
```

But after the second iteration of the loop the array will be again

```
{ 1, 2 }
```

Instead write

```
 for ( i = 0; i < num / 2; i++ )
 {
     temp = *(arr+i);
     *(arr+i) = *(arr+(num-i-1));
     *(arr+(num-i-1)) = temp;
 }
```

Also declare variables in minimal scopes where they are used. For example

```
 for ( size_t i = 0; i < num / 2; i++ )
 {
     int temp = *(arr+i);
     *(arr+i) = *(arr+(num-i-1));
     *(arr+(num-i-1)) = temp;
 }
```